# Problems with HTML5 shiv and elements appended to the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html, modernizr

I am having an issue with getting html 5 to work on elements added to the body in IE. I am using the HTML 5 shiv included in [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) but it is the same problem with any other HTML 5 library.

It works fine for any element except HTML 5 elements added directly to the body, which gives the same error message as if I was using jQuery without the shiv (*Unexpected call to method or property access*). This is a breaking example in IE (7, 8) with Modernizr or html5.js loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('body').append('<nav class="test"></nav>');
    $('.test').html("Testing HTML 5");
});
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe Bartlett adressed your problem in [this](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/) article. He explaines the problem and shows a solution (HTML5 innerShiv) for it.

The solution for IE8 and below would be to insert his [script](http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/innershiv.js) and than wrap all your html5 content in an `innerShiv(...)` before inserting it into the dom

```
$("body").append(innerShiv("<nav class=\"test\"></nav>"));
```

Comment: Awesome. Stumbled across innerShiv but didn't think it applies to my problem. Apparently it did, and worked great.

Comment: @Daff: FYI: the newly released JQuery 1.7 includes the innerShiv hack for IE

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the HTML5 shiv is adding the HTML5 elements to the DOM on page load and then when you add the DOM elements after that, the IE engine fails to recognize them because they were not there at page load when the shiv was applied.

Wondering if the best bet here is to do another `document.createElement("nav");`?

Comment: Tried that already, it didn't work. Adding HTML 5 elements dynamically after the DOM page is ready and shived works fine, too. Just not when added to the body.